# Using LUIS to extract an entity from a user response to a prompt for text and to store the output

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer, azure-language-understanding

I just can't find any info on this!!!

Please see the image.  I want to capture the "number" from the user response as a variable (property) but can't see how to.  Any ideas?!

I want to be able to do this within the composer, not with code. Surely @prebuilt number is storing the recognized entity - how do I set a variable (property) to the value of the entity? Thanks.

[Here's the image of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr2Ih.png)

Answer (score 0):

LOL - solved! The answer is to use coalesce.  Keeping it here for reference for others.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uEzm.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).